# Using Cassandra CQL3 with Python web framework

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, cassandra, web-frameworks

I am trying to build a movie web application using Django. I decided to go with Cassandra as the back end. After studying cassandra for quite some time I found that the Thrift APIs are legacy now and the community is encouraging to use CQL 3.0 However in Django I am not aware of any support for cql. As far as I know there are:
https://github.com/vaterlaus/django_cassandra_backend
https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa

But both follow the Thrift API. Also I couldn't find many examples of Cassandra and Django integration like MongoDB. I have decided upon using Cassandra after quite some research and seeing the power of CQL 3.0 I dont want to abandon my database choice. Instead I am willing to look for other web frameworks in Python like Pylons, Flask etc. So any suggestion on that? And as I have used Django in the past I want to continue to use it, however the principle advantage of Django which is the Django ORM for relational databases isn't applicable here. Is there any way to integrate MySQL and Cassandra with Django to make it work? Also is there any tutorial of setting up Cassandra with Django besides the Twissandra example?

Besides observing the settings.py of Twissandra it says:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'         
DATABASE_NAME = 'dev.db'
```

Link : https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra/blob/master/settings.py

How come it specifies sqlite3 if it is working on Cassandra? Am I missing some kind of integration here?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for an object mapper, I suggest looking at cqlengine.  (Disclaimer: it's my project  :))  It's been in development for over 2 years and is being used by quite a number of large companies.

http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

As for using it with Django, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cassandra-engine/

Answer (score 1):

There are two subjects here.

### About a better cassandra driver

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver, it uses CQL, it is simple and powerful.

### About a Django / Cassandra

Well, there is no simple solution here. There is a [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/) project but it focuses on Mongo and GAE.

I would advise you to use a RDMS (MySQL/PostgreSQL) for most of your stuff and only use cassandra when necessary.

Yes you can also use other webframework like tornado, but handling things like sessions, authentication, forms, is painful when you are used to it.

Twissandra uses sqlite3 only because django *requires* to use a database to work. So there's no django/cassandra integration at all.

---

This is outside the scope of your question: If you want to make a movie web app, you probably don't need cassandra for the core data. You will probably only need it for things like rating, stats, maybe storage. For the core data, a standard RDMS will probably be much better.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. But more than a better driver I am looking for a CQL Object mapper.